# Modding Unreal Engine 4 officials games, modifying .uasset

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new in Modding (I already made Big Mods principaly on GTA V or Skyrim) , and I would like to modify Tropico 6 code .
It's a pc game , made with Unreal Engine 4 . 
So I unpacked the .pak , to find the main .uasset but it's seems when I try to modify this file with
Unreal Engine 4 , it's need the source code to load the project ,
So is there any way to rebuild the source with the project , or to modify .uasset ?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: "So is there any way to rebuild the source with the project" no.

Comment: so the .uasset ?